# Why does upload a model to HuggingFace repository so slow?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have a problem, I'm trying to push a model to HuggingFace repository. The problem is that it says uploading for the past 16 hours and that's just the pytorch_model bin file which is about 850MB. I am using the LFS. I have tried to manually add the files to the repository which takes an eternity that I am not willing to wait, there's no completion percentage so you are not aware if it's progressing or hanging.
I have tried using the git commands, same long wait.
However, if I try to upload to Github rather than HuggingFace, it doesn't take an eternity 30 mins at most. I felt as if I wasted my time doing all this preprocessing and training for nothing.
Any suggestions or similar problems ?