# Problem Uploading Large Files to Hugging Face: Slow Speeds and Interruptions

Tags: git, performance, huggingface, huggingface-hub

I'm facing issues with uploading large model files to Hugging Face.
I managed a large upload once using the webinterface, after several interuptions and restarts, but in order to automatize things i want to upload from commandline, right now using the HuggingFace-CLI command. The upload speeds seem to be capped at around 140 to 180 kB/s, and when dealing with 16 GB files, a single upload takes about 40 hours.
However, the upload process is interrupted at least every 24 hours due to nightly internet connection resets (common in my area).

**Question:** How can I achieve a reliable and faster upload of large files to Hugging Face given these challenges? (with main focus on `reliable`)

#### Details:

- I've installed Git and Git LFS, and I'm using a repository I created s public in Hugging Face.
- I've already run `huggingface-cli lfs-enable-largefiles` locally for the repository.
- My internet connection is stable during the day but experiences brief disconnections at night. This is due to the `PPP Session Termination` occurring once a day with my ISP (and is common here in Germany)
- The upload cap at 140 kB/s is not due to the limits of my Internet connection, and i can start a bunch of model uploads at the same time, each having the same speed of around 140 kB/s. So it's clearly a limitation of huggingface.

#### Upload Command:

This is the command line i use to start the upload (repo-name, filename and token changed)

```bash
huggingface-cli upload maddes8cht/my-repo-id ggml-my-filename.gguf --commit-message "upload ggml-my-filename.gguf" --token hf_***xyz*** --repo-type model
```

This is the message i get in the middle of the night (some chars in the credentials/key randomly changed):

```bash
ggml-my-filename.gguf:   7%|███▊                                                   | 1.84G/26.4G [3:09:29<933:28:46, 7.31kB/s]urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /lfs.huggingface.co/repos/49/89/49892f641ccec0867ad7ad57124c3eff9394b4a087f90e21c663d5c2ejx01676/62651a007cef883c09356e3dda718f929da9116281a7b68b868911461e38b408?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA4N7VTTLO27GPWFUO%2F20230919%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230919T035725Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=ef7d51dc72c76dcd2cce5b127165e3b866998e523779ef0f097d92vc9c327b86&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&partNumber=70&uploadId=popfIEAPsJRDCOGCSX8_FfNpj.V8AApuAeF9iXBFyOLY0hG.al3qHt_EURXzg8fa729TGck2r7qzGvd5QWpIxZ7HP.M8vM9G2Co1Cz7woD7Tnt7DXYkzxRZEJYeC.7cI&x-id=UploadPart (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\_commit_api.py", line 382, in _wrapped_lfs_upload
    lfs_upload(operation=operation, lfs_batch_action=batch_action, token=token)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\lfs.py", line 222, in lfs_upload
    _upload_multi_part(operation=operation, header=header, chunk_size=chunk_size, upload_url=upload_action["href"])
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\lfs.py", line 318, in _upload_multi_part
    else _upload_parts_iteratively(operation=operation, sorted_parts_urls=sorted_parts_urls, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\lfs.py", line 374, in _upload_parts_iteratively
    part_upload_res = http_backoff("PUT", part_upload_url, data=fileobj_slice)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_http.py", line 258, in http_backoff
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_http.py", line 63, in send
    return super().send(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /lfs.huggingface.co/repos/49/89/49892f641ccec0867ad7ad57124c3eff9394b4a087f90e21c663d5c2e5601676/62651a007cef883c09356e3dda718f929da9116281a7b68b868911461e38b408?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA4N7VTTLO27GPWFUO%2F20230919%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20fd09ZUT035725Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=ef7d51dc72c76dcd2xye5b127165e3b866998e523779ef0f097d92c19c327b86&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&partNumber=70&uploadId=popfIEAPsJRDCOGCSX8_FfNpj.V8AApuAeF9iXBFyOLY0hG.al3qHt_EURXzg8fa729TGck2r7qzGvd5QWpIxZ7HP.M8vM9G2Co1Cz7woD7Tnt7DXYkzxRZEJYeC.7cI&x-id=UploadPart (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)')))"), '(Request ID: 10870c92-77d0-4700-bc4e-f44baa646e77)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\Scripts\huggingface-cli-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\commands\huggingface_cli.py", line 49, in main
    service.run()
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\commands\upload.py", line 183, in run
    print(self._upload())
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\commands\upload.py", line 244, in _upload
    return upload_file(
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\hf_api.py", line 849, in _inner
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\hf_api.py", line 3460, in upload_file
    commit_info = self.create_commit(
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\hf_api.py", line 849, in _inner
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\hf_api.py", line 2934, in create_commit
    upload_lfs_files(
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\_commit_api.py", line 392, in upload_lfs_files
    _wrapped_lfs_upload(filtered_actions[0])
  File "C:\Users\Mathias\anaconda3\envs\convert\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\_commit_api.py", line 384, in _wrapped_lfs_upload
    raise RuntimeError(f"Error while uploading '{operation.path_in_repo}' to the Hub.") from exc
RuntimeError: Error while uploading 'ggml-my-filename.gguf' to the Hub.
ggml-my-filename.gguf:   7%|███▉
```

Right now it seems impossible for me to ever finish an upload of models in that size.

**Note:**
This question has similarities with the unanswered question [Why does upload a model to HuggingFace repository so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70828240/20124484) , but contains further aspects and details